# Video in Android Webview is not playing in Samsung Phones

Tags: java, android, html, webview, samsung-mobile

I am developing an app with a webview in it. I tried to play a video from the app using some phones and found out that the video is not playing on Samsung phones but it played well in other phones. What could be the reason for it?

```
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_video, container, false);

        WebView webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.web_view);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        webView.loadUrl("https://imjws05.cafe24.com/newyklec/");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the Websetting to your webView

```
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

and add this code in your `oncreate` methode of your  parent activity where fragment is called before `setcontentview`

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still no good. I have found the reason of the problem and it is the newest update of Google Chrome. When I updated the Chrome app, the video on the webview in the app doesn't work. Any ideas to fix this? @Dev.Barai